# Regex : Matching phone numbers starting with NNN and having 10 numbers

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I need to match phone numbers that :

- start with 010 or 012 or 016 or 019
- Consist of 10 numbers exactly

Can you please help me on how to match numbers using PHP and regex?

Comment: How about `010-123-4567`? `(010) 123-4567`?

Comment: no only numbers without dashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return preg_match('/^01[0269]\\d{7}$/', $theStringToTest);
```

This will match 0, 1, one of (0, 2, 6, 9), and then any 7 numbers (3+7==10). The `^` means start of string and `$` means end of string.

Comment: when applying this it gave me 0 no results although the string to test contain numbers

example : 

$dido = preg_match('/^01[0269]\\d{7}$/',$kokii);

echo $dido;

Comment: @Net: What is in `$kokii`? Is there some trailing new lines or spaces in it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use `^01[0269][0-9]{7}$`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex

```
/\b(010|012|016|019)[0-9]{7}\b/g
```